# powershell with csom clientcontext castto method

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, csom

How do I put this c# CSOM in powershell

TaxonomyField taxonomyField = clientContext.CastTo(field);

I have tried:
$taxonomyField 
= $clientContext.CastTo[Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField]

but does not work.

Answer (score 9):

Spent all day on this. Hope someone finds this useful! It has to do with invoking Generic Methods (any time you see  in a function call) within powershell. I've compacted it down to one line, because I like it that way.

Also, the $global:ctx is just my client context object.

```
$txField = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext].GetMethod("CastTo").MakeGenericMethod([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField]).Invoke($global:ctx, $field)
```

Answer (score 2):

Start with a normal SharePoint CSOM Field that represents a managed metadata field.

```
$field = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Field]$someFieldFromItemListOrContentType;
```

Casting the field directly as the taxonomy type will be null.

```
$taxonomyField = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField]$field;
```

Casting the `TypedObject` property to the taxonomy field will not be null.

```
$taxonomyField = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField]$field.TypedObject;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField]$taxonomyField
```

Does that work?

I don't have access to SharePoint but this is how casting in PowerShell can be done.

```
PS C:\> $taxField = 10
PS C:\> [String]$taxField
10
```

Comment: I need to convert $field to Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField

Comment: Well, the casting is done that way! Does it work for you? I updated my answer to show some generic example.

Comment: no, it does not work, looks like have to call clientContext.CastTo, but I don't know to call it with <TaxonomyField> in Powershell

Comment: TaxonomyField taxonomyField = clientContext.CastTo<TaxonomyField>(field); CSOM code works